# How to replace buildQuery on gridfilters plugin on ExtJs 6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am using Extjs 6 and I want to put filters on my grids. I used gridfilters plugin but I can't found the buildQuery method that I have used on Extjs 4. How can I replace it?
this is the code in Extjs 4.2.2:

```
features: [{
            ftype: 'filters',
            encode: false,
            local: false,
            sorters: '',
            filters: this.createFiltres(),
            buildQuery: this.bQuery,
          }]
```

I added plugin: 'gridfilter' but it's not working. I need the buildQuery.

Comment: If you remove parenthesis after `this.createFilters`, maybe `buildQuery` will work?

Comment: I used this code on 4.2.2 version. It is not working anymore. in Extjs 6, the plugin 'gridfilters' replace 'Ext.ux.feature.Features'. I want to how can I replace buildQuery in Extjs 6?

Comment: I used this code on 4.2.2 version. It is not working anymore. in Extjs 6, the plugin 'gridfilters' replace 'Ext.ux.feature.Features'. I want to know how can I replace buildQuery in Extjs 6? I refer to this link: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?302253-Ext-JS-Filter-Add-datatype-of-Property-to-Filter-params-in-URL
I want to know please how to change the parameter 'filter' in query parameter to 'id_equal' (the id is the name of the column I searched with.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such method (buildQyery) in the actual implementation of the gridfilters plugin. The plugin just works with store filters. One way to solve your problem might be to handle this in the listener for grid's filterchange event..